# Permission for location is granted while debugging however not granted on android system

Tags: android, android-permissions

This is the debugging result for the check of the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission, this means that the permission has been granted for the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

[image: This is the debugging result for the check of the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission, this means that the permission has been granted for the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION]

Now when I try to use the location service, i don't get any results, so i checked in the android system itself after debugging and found that the permission has not been granted to the location after it was already granted while debugging.

[image: the permission has not been granted to the location]

what could be the problem ?

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice 6.0.1 MMB29M

Comment: Does the dialog appear to request the permission?

Comment: p.s. You should copy and paste code here rather than a screenshot.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice no

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i wanted to prove that the result of the debugging was that it has been granted

Comment: I think your `else if` should just be an `if`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes that is correct, however does not solve the main issue.

Comment: I am not very familiar with requesting permissions at run time. Hopefully there are others here that can help. You will probably have to wait for at least 24 hours to get more feedback and hopefully a useful answer.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thank you for your time, I hope that too because I've been looking everywhere and haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved however I still have no idea where the problem was, if someone knew please let me know, the solution is that i used a library that is called https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher, which requested the permission successfully, it also uses annotations that simplify the code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of issue in the past while trying to add runtime permissions to an existing app (unable to get the request dialog to appear...). Code looked good but was unable to get the dialog on a real device.

My issue was that my target SDK was lower than Android 6.0 (API level 23). You need to target at least API level 23 in order to use runtime permission (specified in the first part of [this article](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)).

Not sure if your issue is the same but I hope it could help :)

Comment: Thank you for your response, however i'm already targeting API level 25 while having this issue

Comment: Did you also declare them in your manifest file? This is also required even if you are using runtime permissions

Answer (score 0):

use this library https://github.com/ParkSangGwon/TedPermission

very useful!!!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've already found one, however I'm trying to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the `Android Version >= M`, You must ask both `Permission - ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` to get the location service. A general `Runtime Permission` asking code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
            (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                    (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        }, 1); // 1 is requestCode
        return;

    }
    else{
         //permission already granted enable your location here
    }
}
```

Handle Request:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
switch (requestCode) {

    case 1:
        if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Toast.makeText(your_activity.this,"PERMISSION_DENIED",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
          else {
                Toast.makeText(your_activity.this,"PERMISSION_GRANTED",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               // permission granted do something
          }
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, As you can see in the first image, the permission check for the fine location implies that the permission has been granted for the location while it has not been in the system , so by running your code i would run the second part of the if condition "//permission already granted enable your location here" which would not solve the main problem

Comment: If it says permission granted but no in the system, u must check the request handled by u in `onRequestPermissionsResult`, may be u r not doing it properly. update code in question if possible.